# How to force the latex text paragraph to start from new page and not to break in to half in between pages

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs, text

It's a generic question, sorry I dont have any reproducible code.

My question though is simple.

When I am writing a text into the document, and my paragraph, started from page 1 continues to page 2 where after few lines into page 2 it will end.

What I want to know is that is there a method or a package in Latex which automatically pushes the these kind of splitting paragraphs into the next page, where it can write the whole paragraph without breaking it into two pieces spread over two pages ?

Comment: `minipage` environment or `samepage` environment or `\parbox` to name a few possibilities

Comment: @DavidCarlisle..Thanks. The minipage and samepage environment are useful when I know the there is a paragraph which needs to be put into the same page. But it wont do it intelligently. I mean like define it at the start of the chapter and it takes care of paragraph breaking for the whole chapter.

Comment: You can get another hint from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73273).  But you should clarify better what you are looking for: if you are just annoyed because the last two lines of a paragraph wind up in the next page, and you want to prohibit a break unless there are, say, at least three (or, maybe, four) lines on the next page, then you should read about `\widowpenalties`.

Comment: a "paragraph" that can't break over a page isn't really a paragraph so should probably be marked up as `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}` (where `foo` could simply be `minipage`) then the markup would do exactly what you ask. Of course then it is the authors responsibility to ensure the paragraphs fit on a page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle...I understood what you said. Thanks. I will work on it.